# Как запушить проект на GitHub?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Не судите меня строго, пожалуйста.

Не могу запушить проект на GitHub.

Судя по всему, в `VS code` объявлен старый репозиторий в который когда-то пушила проект.

Я создала новый репозиторий и хочу залить туда проект.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать.

Использовала в терминале все команды, которые нужны, чтобы залить проект - не помогло.

Пыталась связать с новым репозиторием, как указано тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792678/how-to-push-a-new-code-to-an-existing-git-repository-in-github, но ничего не сработало.

Новый репозиторий называется pulse_website, вот ссылка на него https://github.com/JuliePahopol/pulse_website.git
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] заранее благодарю за ответ[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это новый репозиторий, то склонируйте репозиторий к себе на ПК для начала, затем поместите туда свои файлы, добавьте их, добавьте коммит и запуште.

Comment: Вывод команд говорит, что старого remote видимо уже нет. Теперь нужно добавить новый адрес remote,

Answer (score 0):

1: после создания любого репозитория выводит вот такое окошко, где, в принципе, и все описано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2: так как у Вас уже есть инициализированный `git`, то пропускаем пару изначальных шагов и запускаем сначала:

1. git remote add [любое название на ваш выбор] [путь]
2. git push -u [название с верху] main(либо в другую ветку)

пример:

1. git remote add abra https://github.com/armensargsyan1993/dsadasd.git
2. git push -u abra main